# Is there a HTTP header size limit that triggers prevent header already sent?

Tags: php, header, limit

Maybe I am missing something, but unfortunately the above suggested link did not help me with the following problem:

I have a file (doctype_head.php) that also has an include of an authentication file for logins that I load first thing on all my webpages. Last time I logged in to check my login-system index.php file I got this warning:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at www.haushalts-geld.de\include\doctype_head.php:40) in www.haushalts-geld.de\login\admin\index.php on line 53
```

I know I get this warning because of a header() call in line 53 in index.php and I also know how to fix it. This warning seems connected to the amount of characters in "doctype_head.php". As far as I know no output is sent before the aforementioned header() call. Otherwise deleting just a few characters from my comments text (`<!--bla bla-->`) in "doctype_head.php" would not have solved the headers already sent warning, I guess. The thing is, everything works fine only if I keep the text in "doctype_head.php" to a certain length. I tested it up to the point where I just have to add one single character to "doctype_head.php" and get the above warning. If I remove this character again, everything works without warning.

So, that's why I wonder if it could be that I am only allowed a certain amount of characters for my HTTP header before my output starts? I thought that the included authentication file within "doctype_head.php" might be the culprit, since this alone is already about 6KB. If so, what can I do to fix this? And if not, any ideas what else I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. PHP source code size has no effect on headers being sent or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, that's why I wonder if it could be that I am only allowed a certain amount of characters for my HTTP header before my output starts?

Not usually.  Something in your application has to output something for output to begin.

> Otherwise deleting just a few characters from my comments text (`<!--bla bla-->`) in "doctype_head.php" would not have solved the headers already sent warning

Your comment style is using HTML comments... not PHP comments.  *Anything* outside of PHP open/close tags is going to be output, *including HTML comments*.  PHP doesn't really know or care about HTML.  It's just going to output it.  Use PHP comments instead, inside PHP tags.  (`/* comment */`)  Better yet, never close your PHP tag.  It's not necessary that you close it.

Comment: Thank's for both of your answers. You were both right. PHP code did not trigger the warning. Indeed, HTML comment tags were the problem, but they did not trigger a headers already sent warning, since output_buffering was set to 4096. As I exceeded this buffering size the headers already sent warning started to kick in.